# Import module with the same alias in nested functions in Python

Tags: python, import, nested-function

I note the standard method for importing.

```
import module as m
```

I also note that one can import a module within a function as follows.

```
def someFunction():
    import module as m

    # do some things
    return
```

I also note that nested funcitons have scope such that *the inner functions variable has a local scope that is limited only to that function*.

Given the above, I want to (**safely**) **import two different modules** but **both with the same alias** as follows: In this example, the two modules are `test_params` and `test_params2` and the alias (common to both, but nested) is `p`.

```
import test_params as p

print(p.x)


def some_code():
    import test_params2 as p

    print(p.x)

    return

some_code()
```

If `test_params` has x=100 and `test_params2` has x=10 then the expected result would be:

```
100
10
```

Which it is when i test it.

My question is this: Is the above acceptable and understood (pythonic, with no conflicts) or is there a better method?

Comment: it is noted that the import will be performed every time the function is called which in some cases might be suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

- "The import statement combines two operations; it searches for the named module, then it binds the results of that search to a name in the local scope."

  - This means that you will not "pollute" your namespace by having an additional import inside of a function, and it will simply override the entire module. You can test this out by referring to something in `test_params` that's not in `test_params2`, inside `some_code` (it won't work)
  - However, the import will be performed every time the function is called. This may or may not be a problem (depends on performance).
  - Additionally, this method isn't as flexible because it won't allow for *overrides* (e.g. override a mapping if it exists, but preserve mappings that aren't overridden)

If you want a way to designate different module-sourced mappings for different functions, which allows for overrides (i.e. default values from a base module), you can do something like this:

```py
import test_params
import test_params2


def module_map(*modules):
    result = {}
    for module in modules:
        new_values = {item:getattr(module, item) for item in dir(module) if not item.startswith("__")}
        result.update(new_values)
    return result

def some_code():
    val_map = module_map(test_params, test_params2)
    print("out2:", val_map)

    return

print("out:", module_map(test_params))
some_code()
```

test_params:

```
y = 8
x = 50
z = 10
```

test_params2:

```
y = 200
x = 100
```

Output:

```
out: {'x': 50, 'y': 8, 'z': 10}
out2: {'x': 100, 'y': 200, 'z': 10}
```

Comment: this is the important part:  "you will not "pollute" your namespace by having an additional import inside of a function".   But the other points are noted too.